# Compound nodes with multiple parent in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cytoscape.js, bayesian-networks

I am creating an editor for bayesian nets (template notations) in cytoscape.js. In the template notation sometimes I need to have a node with two parents. Like the graph in the picture.

[image]
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/cf73312544e33691bbf72d62687ae5328597c59b/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f437a4e796b2e706e67

Taken from: https://github.com/jluttine/tikz-bayesnet

I could not find such a plugin, I appreciate it if someone has suggestions.

Comment: Please remove d3js tag. Cytoscape is not d3.

Comment: Well, if you know any other library in d3, that would be appreciate it as well. I don't necessarily need to use that library.

Comment: I am not sure if this is supported in cytoscape. One thing you can try is to have two nodes (each being child of one parent). Then programmatically ensure that they always overlap.

Comment: Something like that : https://jsfiddle.net/4x80kra6/1/ ?

Comment: @Majestic you mean to use a different notation for my compound nodes?

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, this is not supported in Cytoscape.js. The compound graph model in Cytoscape.js is "disjoint hierarchical" - a given node can have only one direct parent.